How do generative models generate?
I am trying to understand the difference between discriminative models and generative models in machine learning. One of the helpful answers at Stack Overflow is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879432/what-is-the-difference-between-a-generative-and-a-discriminative-algorithm/879591#879591
In the top answer (see the above link) in the above question, there was a simple example where there are only four data points of the form (x,y). The author of the answer said the following: "The distribution p(y|x) is the natural distribution for classifying a given example x into a class y, which is why algorithms that model this directly are called discriminative algorithms. Generative algorithms model p(x,y), which can be transformed into p(y|x) by applying Bayes rule and then used for classification. However, the distribution p(x,y) can also be used for other purposes. For example, you could use p(x,y) to generate likely (x,y) pairs."
I don't quite understand how one could use p(x,y) to generate likely (x,y) pairs. I would be interested to see an example of (x,y) pair that is generated by using the joint probability distribution p(x,y)? Also, why can the conditional probability distribution p(y|x) not be used to generate new pairs?
Also, I take it to be the case that the joint probability distribution p(x,y) is $$P(X \cap Y)$$ where x is an element of X and y is an element of Y. Is my understanding correct? Thank you so much!

Please ask only one question per post.

This could be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11674/generating-random-samples-from-a-density-function
